# Dense_rank in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have the following table 'CarN' in sql server

```
    carID      ownerID      Make      Model         Year        Color
    C11         O11         Honda       A           2010        Red       
    C12         blue        Honda       B           2012        Blue      
    C13         O12         Maru        B           2014        Yellow    
    C12         blue        Honda       B           2012        Blue
```

when I execute the query

```
select  *,dense_Rank() over(partition by model order by carid)
from carN

carID      ownerID      Make      Model         Year        Color     Rank
C11         O11         Honda       A           2010        Red         1
C12         blue        Honda       B           2012        Blue        1
C12         blue        Honda       B           2012        Blue        1
C13         O12         Maru        B           2014        Yellow      2
```

In result how it happened to get the same number '1' for the first three records ?

Comment: I'm confused.  What is your question?  It is assigning "1" because that is what your query specifies -- without knowing which column is which, it is hard to provide more details.  What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hope its clear now

Comment: do you want to know how dense rank function works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way dense rank works is like below:

1. First partition by the partition by clause; which is `model`. So here are two partitions as there are two models

**partition 1**

```
carID      ownerID      Make      Model         Year        Color
C11         O11         Honda       A           2010        Red
```

**partition 2**

```
carID      ownerID      Make      Model         Year        Color    
C12         blue        Honda       B           2012        Blue      
C13         O12         Maru        B           2014        Yellow    
C12         blue        Honda       B           2012        Blue
```

2. In each partition give ranks ordering by the order by clause which is carID. Note that in partition 2 since two records have same carID they will be given same rank, and since `car12` is less than in value than `car13` and default order here is `ASC`, so both records with `car12` will have same rank as 1

**partition 1**

```
carID      ownerID      Make      Model         Year        Color  rank
C11         O11         Honda       A           2010        Red     1 as it is the only record
```

**partition 2**

```
carID      ownerID      Make      Model         Year        Color    rank
C12         blue        Honda       B           2012        Blue      1
C13         O12         Maru        B           2014        Yellow    2
C12         blue        Honda       B           2012        Blue      1
```

3. Now collate all partitions together to get the output that you see.

Answer (score 1):

Let's partition your data set according to your SQL statement:

```
dense_Rank() over(partition by model order by carid)

Model        carID      Rank
  A          C11          1
  -------------------------
  B          C12          1
  B          C12          1
  B          C13          2
```

The first partition (Model A) only has 1 row so `Rank = 1`

The first two rows of the second partition have the same `carID`, so both of them have `Rank = 1`. If you want them to have different rank, add in a tie-breaker or  use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
-- this will still give the same rank when the tie-breaker column is equal
dense_Rank() over(partition by model order by carid, AnotherColumn)


-- guaranteed to give different ranking for each row with a partition
-- if the rows have the same carID, which row gets what number is undetermined
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by model order by carid)
```